# PySpark : multiple warnings about illegal use and hadoop native when executing pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm very new to PySpark, I'm trying to execute the pyspark command in my anaconda prompt then it popped out many warnings that I'm confused of or which warning should I really care that could be future problems. Is there any way to fix these? I'm afraid these warnings will cause future errors when I'm trying to learn PySpark on my jupyter notebook..

```
(base) C:\Users\Kiwi>pyspark
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/C:/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.1.2.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
21/06/07 13:42:26 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
```

Comment: u need not worry

Comment: but what about warning `All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release` it seems intimidating, will it prevent me from doing anything in PySpark?

Comment: people as in professionals